# Probability of Non-exceedance modelled by Normal Distribution Question

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, mean

The complete question is:
A number of pre-cast beams are to be laid side-by-side to form a bridge deck which will later
receive an in-situ topping. The beams are nominally 300mm wide, but in practice they are
found to vary in width because of shrinkage and errors in pre-casting. A sample of beams was
selected at random and the sampled beams were found to have the following widths (assume
uniformity along the length):

309 294 313 259 313 302 305 302 304 303
282 284 294 306 305 296 307 310 299 308
294 303 303 301 295 299 306 303 302 306
297 305 305 303 289 316 298 317 296 295
290 299 291 293 301 297 311 301 309 302

(a) Examine the data by choosing an appropriate class interval and plotting a histogram.
After modifying the data, if necessary, compute:

(b) The sample mean and

(c) The sample standard deviation and coefficient of variation.

**(d) If the beam depths exhibit the same sample statistics as the beam widths, consider a
square beam with nominal dimensions 300 x 300mm and find the weight (per metre) that has
a 95% probability of non-exceedance. You may assume that the specific weight of the
concrete beam is deterministic and equal to 24 kN/m3.
It may also be assumed that the weight per unit length can be modelled by a normal
distribution.**

I have worked out the mean, standard deviation and coefficient of variation already for the beam widths.

Mean = 300.44

Standard deviation = 9.47

I am unsure on how to answer part d.

Comment: (d) is unanswerable without making strong assumptions that have not been stated in the question.  The most important of these concerns whether the beam depths are independent of the beam widths. Most people might assume either perfect dependence or else independence are implied, *but both those assumptions contradict the last sentence of (d)!*